# Will I lose old Google Analytics data if I create a new account

Tags: google-analytics

I am looking to create a new account for a website for Google Analytics data. I will be taking over the analytics for a client, but want to be able to compare old historical data to the analytics.

If I create a new account and Google stops tracking in the old analytics account, will I lose that data or will I be able to go back into the old account and see it at any time before the tracking code got changed? I don't need to see old data in the new account or new data in the old account, just want to be sure I won't lose old data in the old account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is to get the client to use the Administration › User Management settings in order to grant you access to the current account via your own Google Account. They can grant you full access.

There's no need to actually start using a new account. This way you won't loose historic data for the site.

Comment: So does that mean they will lose historical data if we decide to make a new account and switch the tracking code? The reason we might want to make a new account is that the site analytics are tracked in the web developer's account that created the old site and not the owner of the old website. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't find any solid info, but I believe the historic data would be lost. There's a few ideas discussed here though - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/lz_gVxtupkM and these might be helpful - http://otherchin.com/blog/2013/03/how-to-transfer-google-analytics-account-without-losing-data/ and http://otherchin.com/blog/2013/03/how-to-give-google-analytics-access-for-only-single-websites/